# Git & NPM commands not recognized

Tags: git, npm, operating-system

I keep getting
'git' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

and

'npm' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

I have installed both, and have also manually added the paths to environment variables -> system variables -> path which were already present. I have also uninstalled and reinstalled both applications. I am now out of ideas. Any help would be appreciated.

**Edit**

Using Windows 10, C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\nodejs; are the current paths. Ive checked program files and the folders with the installed files are there

Comment: Where are you getting those error messages?

Comment: @mkrieger1 in the command line. Its where I prefer to do my git stuff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure to open a new CMD, and check your %PATH% does indeed  refers to those tools.
Type:

```
where git
where npm
```

You should see for instance `C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe`

As noted in the command, if that is not the case, re-installing Windows is recommended.

Comment: Sorry for the slow response, I was away from my desk. I get the same response with where.
'where' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file. Seems like maybe a command line issue?

Comment: @MarkSmith You would get that error is you are not in a CMD, but a bash session. Open a CMD first. (Or: you are in a CMD, but with a `%PATH%` quite incomplete, without `C:\Windows\System32`.

Comment: I am in a CMD session, I only use command line for Git. I checked environment variables and it did have %SystemRoot%\system32. However I did add C:\Windows\System32 to make sure that wasnt the issue. It still doesnt work

Comment: @MarkSmith Did you relaunch a new CMD? Does `dir C:\Windows\System32\where.exe` work?

Comment: Launched a new cmd, restarted etc. Just added that line and it still doesnt work. At this point im thinking I just reinstall windows

Comment: @MarkSmith Agreed. I don't know how a `C:\Windows\System32`  without basic commands like `where.exe` could work...

Comment: reinstalling windows has done the trick, must have been an issue with my OS. Thanks for your help

Comment: @MarkSmith Well done! I have edited the answer accordingly.